# Unspecified error (MS Visual Database Tools) when creating a table using GUI

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssms

I added my user to ***db_ddladmin*** role, but initially i had my own custom role with rights to create a table for that user. Either way creating a table using TSQL works, being part of both roles. Problem occurs when i try to create a table using GUI, tables -> new table, i get the ***Unspecified Error(MS Visual Database Tools)***

However if i add that user as a ***db_owner*** , it works. I would just like to know if there is any right in particular that i might have missed which specifies whether user can create a table through GUI or not?

Note:
I am using SSMS 17.4 and SQL Server 2016.User is part of a domain created login.

Comment: Try to see what code is sent to server by SSMS using SQL Server Profiler. If your user is able to create table using T-SQL it's NOT a permission issue.

Comment: I create a user with pw (no login) in a partial contained database. Gave following permission. `GRANT CREATE TABLE TO Billy GO
GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::dbo TO Billy GO`  and was able to create table with tsql and GUI without any error. Using ssms 17.4, SQL 2017 CU2

Comment: @SqlWorldWide I did the same before and it worked. For this particular domain user it does not. However i have noticed that table creation through the gui works if the user is part of db_securityadmin role, as well as the ddl_admin role. which previously didnt work if he was only in ddl_admin role

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question. After a some testing i noticed that the user needs to have Control permission on the database in order to be able to create tables using GUI. That is why `db_securityadmin` and `db_owner` worked.

Now i have tried before posted question to create a new login and user, that worked just fine. For some reason this domain user was problematic, so i explicitly granted him that permission. I dont think this happens occasionally, but if anyone encounters this issue that i have, i hope this helps. And some clarification if anyone has would be greatly appreciated.